# pdflatex and biber: biblatex inserts blank page with single comma on M1 mac

Tags: biblatex, pdftex, biber, mactex

I have both an M1 and an Intel Mac laptop.  When I use the file below with the `pdflatex` and `biber` commands on my M1 machine, I see a page with a single comma before the title page.  It works fine on my Intel laptop.  If I comment out the second line below, the page with the comma goes away.

Here's the output of latex -v on my M1 Mac:

```
pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022)
kpathsea version 6.3.4
Copyright 2022 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty. Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.37; using libpng 1.6.37
Compiled with zlib 1.2.11; using zlib 1.2.11
Compiled with xpdf version 4.03
```

Here are the commands I'm using:

```
pdflatex file.tex
biber file.tex
```

Here's the file:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
​
%\usepackage[natbib=true, uniquename=false, minbibnames=1, maxbibnames=10, maxcitenames=1, maxcitenames=3, backend=biber, ibidtracker=false, style=authoryear-luh-ipw]{biblatex} 
​
\newcommand{\blind}{0} % 1=blind, 0=not blind
\newcommand{\titl}{Science is Great}
​
\if0\blind
​
\title{\titl} 
​
\author{Joanne Harvard\and Sally Radcliffe} 
​
\fi
 
\if1\blind
\title{\titl}
\fi
​
\begin{document}
\maketitle
​
hi
\end{document}
​
%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% TeX-engine: default
%%% End:
```

Comment: I get `! LaTeX Error: Unicode character ​ (U+200B)
               not set up for use with LaTeX.` from the posted code

Comment: You seem to be using emacs, `M-x whitespace-mode`  will show [this buffer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n24Lv.png) with the U+200B zero width spaces in red.

Answer (score 3):

the error is unrelated to the operating system or pdftex version

```
! LaTeX Error: Unicode character ​ (U+200B)
               not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

U+200B is zero-width space, you have *loads* of these, at ends of lines and after each comma in the biblatex option list.

Retype without the control codes and the error will go.

After *any* error the pdf output is not intended to be usable, just, at best, a debugging aid.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[natbib=true,uniquename=false,minbibnames=1,maxbibnames=10,maxcitenames=1,maxcitenames=3,backend=biber,ibidtracker=false,style=authoryear-luh-ipw]{biblatex}

\newcommand{\blind}{0} % 1=blind, 0=not blind
\newcommand{\titl}{Science is Great}

\if0\blind
\title{\titl}
\author{Joanne Harvard\and Sally Radcliffe}
\fi

\if1\blind
\title{\titl}
\fi

\begin{document}
\maketitle
xs
hi
\end{document}
​
```